# PHP Stateless Authentication

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm not new to PHP, but for authentication I've always used sessions. 
Now I'd like to make stateless authentication, so I can't use sessions, because there might be many server instances, and they won't share session data, so what I thought is have a session table on my database, and do the following:

- Store a cookie with a token in the client's machine
- Have a *token* column in the session table, something like a GUID, so all entries with the same token can be accessed by the client
- Also store the ip of the client, so people with the same token but different IP can't read the data

Something like this

```
id   | token        | ip         | key       | data
1    | a-guid       | 190.0.0.1  | username  | encrypted-data
2    | a-guid       | 190.0.0.1  | is_logged | more-encrypted-data 
3    | other-guid   | 190.2.2.2  | is_logged | some-more-data
```

So the user with a cookie with token a-guid and ip 190.0.0.1 can access *username* and *is_logged*

But I'm not sure about security, if someone could somehow get your token from your cookies, and your ip, and he/she could send a request with your cookie token and your ip, it would have complete access to your account.

Should I have some special considerations?

Comment: You obviously need TLS or a similar security mechanism

Comment: Having a session table isn't stateless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have the same misconceptions about the mechanisms of sessions, that a lot of people have. Even though there are a few mechanisms in which PHP is able to track sessions, the most typical way sessions are tracked is already by exactly the same mechanism you are proposing, namely: by using a plain old regular cookie with some unique token.

The thing that differentiates the way PHP sessions utilize cookies from the way cookies are otherwise typically used, is that sessions [don't set any expiration date on the cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) (thus causing the browser to typically discard them when you close the browser), and (and this is where your proposed method corresponds) only filling the cookie with a session id (similar to your proposed token) as its data.

So then, where does that leave us? Well, for one thing... the security concern you have (intercepting your proposed token) is relevant to regular sessions as well (intercepting the session id). If you want to avoid this security concern, you'd have to start utilizing secure transfers ([HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) using SSL/TLS).

And as far as using a central session table, as you proposed... this is indeed a common route to take. And what do you know? PHP already has a mechanism in place to 'easily' take care of this with regular sessions, namely [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

This function allows you register functions (or since 5.4 an object with interface `SessionHandlerInterface`) that read and write to any persistent storage you seem fit. This could mean some session table in your database as well. Be aware though that writing these functions/methods can be tricky. But you can probably find good examples on the web and/or Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is interesting, and it could really help me out, so I can use a database to store my data.

Comment: fireeyedboy really nailed it. I was going to say pretty much the exact same thing. PHP already has this in place, and rewriting it probably won't solve your problem (it also probably won't perform any better). It is very, very common, however, to store the ID in the database and maybe attach it to a username and profile or something similar. Check out the other [session functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php), most notably the function fireeyedboy pointed out `session_set_save_handler()`, but all the others as well.

Answer (score -1):

What if you create a random string when they authenticate, save this in the DB for the session and use it to encrypt the above information? Any server that got the token could use the stored secret to decrypt the session but it couldn't be faked by a third party.

All that you'd save in the cookie would be the encrypted data plus some value used to look up the secret.

Comment: How does this increase security? If I get your cookie value (which is the only thing that is required), there's still the same security risk, but now with additional overhead (encryption).